# Im trying to understand this code. I was reading a contract to analyze some functions and I couldnt understand this. Can someone explain?

Tags: solidity

```
assembly {
            let data := mload(0x40)
            mstore(data, 0x9264274400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
            mstore(add(data, 0x04), amount)
            mstore(0x40, add(data, 0x24))
            let success := call(gas(), sload(0x52), 0, data, 0x24, data, 0x20)
            if success { result := mload(data) }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is calling the contract whose address is stored at slot 0x52.

The first 4 bytes `0x92642744` are the function signature. From [the Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory/) it corresponds to `mintNFT(uint256)`.